# Is there any graphic library of C on mac?

Tags: c, macos, graphic

I want to use C to draw some graphic on Mac, is there any graphic library provided on Mac?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/technologies/mac/graphics-and-animation.html

Comment: If you're looking for 2D graphics, SDL works on Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this link http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Getting_started#Mac_OS_X 
You might also need to learn about GLUT before developing any useful graphics application.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL is available. What kind of graphics do you need?